# Understanding base fee per gas and its related priority

Tags: eip-1559

When calling `getFeeHistory` as below, if I understand correctly by using the "pending" parameter we get a base fee estimate in the last items of `baseFeePerGas` to use when creating a transaction.

```
web3.eth.getFeeHistory(1, "pending").then(console.log);
{
   baseFeePerGas: [ '0x7d4f22963', '0x6ddf7199b' ], // [33637411171, 29493762459]
   gasUsedRatio: [ 0.007257119910926353 ],
   oldestBlock: 13010609
}
```

Before London gas price estimation was tied to a target block so it was straightforward to think about a transaction being mined after x block or y seconds.
(1) What is the equivalent now with the `base fee` ? What should I expect from above estimation ?

(2) Is the `base fee` computation deterministic ? I think I read so somewhere but then I don't get why the estimate (here '0x6ddf7199b' or 29493762459 for block 13010610) does not match https://etherscan.io/block/13010610 37.321492006 Gwei.

(3) Why does a miner would prioritise high base fee first as they are burned anyway ? Would it be because it gives more value to their mining reward by deflation ?